# How to Angular2 @Component add css and less?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less

I use @Component with css only in project like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../css/style.css'],
    providers: [CookieService],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

Is there a way to use css and less at the same time? I wish to use css common like bootstrap and my personal less styles like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../css/style.css', '../css/style2.less'],
    providers: [CookieService],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Cant You provide style with link tag?